# Probability Question regarding matrix integer

Tags: probability, matrices

Consider an empty 4x4 matrix. In each row of the matrix we randomly insert one integer. What is the probability that we inserted integers in such a way that each column of the matrix contains only one integer

I am not sure how to even approach this question. Please help

Comment: Think in steps. The first number you insert can't spoil the event. The second insertion can (how?). Assuming the second insertion didn't spoil the event, the third one still can (how?). Then continue for the fourth insertion.

Comment: What does "randomly insert an integer" mean?  How do you choose an integer at random?  The question makes no sense unless you specify a probability distribution.